# Prevent World texture from reflecting on an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, light

I use HDRI for lighting and have a plane made from some glossy material on which my other objects are. And I just can't figure it out how I could achieve that the World doesn't reflect on the plane, only the objects on it.

Under Object > Cycles Setting I cannot find any relevant option for this, my other idea was the light path node, but there I can see no output for world either.

Do I need to use compositor maybe? And if so how?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/cycles-how-do-i-exclude-the-environment-texture-from-reflections

Comment: Thanks for linking this other question, I didn't find it. I've read it but it didn't really give me a perfect solution. The first attempt with "Is Glossy Ray" at the Environment Texture pretty messes up my scene as it affects also other objects not just my plane. The second attempt using material indexing I find unnecessarily complicated, and before accepting that it's the only way to do it somehow, I have an other idea: What If I placed my plane onto a different layer, for that layer I set a different World, then put it together with the compositor? Can different layers have different Worlds?

Comment: I've found a solution to the problem, [see my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/cycles-how-do-i-exclude-the-environment-texture-from-reflections).