# Is there any way to turn off light contribution from the HDR environment maps in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I want to turn off any light contribution to the scene by HDR maps. Background texture must be visible but there should be no light contribution to the scene.

Comment: you can texture a UV sphere and use it as a dome.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/cycles-how-do-i-exclude-the-environment-texture-from-reflections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the ray visibility of the environment for everything, except for the camera.

[image: world ray visibility]

Comment: unchecking the diffuse texture is all I had to do , thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Setup your world material like this:

[image]

Comment: Using ray visibility is somewhat faster than the light path node in a lot of cases (although I'm not sure about this one). This is because it can prevent a sample instead of just zeroing out the sample after it's taken. Not sure that applies in this case, but generally if you can obtain your desired result with the ray vis switches, you should use those instead of the light path node

Comment: Yes, it would be faster in this case, but there are other reasons to use the light path node.