# Minimum amount of illumination in Cycles?

Tags: shaders, lighting, shadows, world

I'm rendering a satellite in orbit of the Earth for a client. The sun is head-on so there is nothing to light the back of the satellite. Since this doesn't look great and more of the satellite should be visible, I want to make it so that shadowed areas aren't as dark. I tried doing this by making the world lighting brighter, which works, but since the satellite is metallic, the shadowed areas of the satellite don't look shadowed at all when viewed at a shallow angle (the background is reflected). How can I make the satellite still look shaded properly but with the shadowed areas still somewhat illuminated?

Comment: Cycles, it's in the title.

Comment: Maby this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/cycles-how-do-i-exclude-the-environment-texture-from-reflections

Comment: Also bluring the background image maby helps making the reflexions less intrusive

Comment: The most complicated way would be to use several passes/ diffrent scene setups and use the envoirment background only as direct/ indirect diffuse pass but not as glossy

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your setup, but couldn't you just put either an emission plane, or a simple reflective plane (to bounce back some light from the sun) "off-screen".

Comment: Thanks. I think that I was under the impression that my shadows being hard to see was unrealistic but upon further analysis, this is physically accurate, so I will keep it.