# How can I remove the multicolored lighting from an environment texture background?

Tags: lighting

How can I remove the multicolored lighting from an environment texture background?

I want a plain white lighting.

I saw this post: [Cycles: How do I exclude the Environment Texture from reflections?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/cycles-how-do-i-exclude-the-environment-texture-from-reflections)

but I am using evee, and evee doesn't provide a glossy shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the color from the World Environment, but keep the lighting strength in B&W, place a RGB to BW Node between your HDRI texture and the Background Node of your world shader:

[image: BW]

If you want to keep the HDRI colors, but still have only white lighting, mix a regular background with the black and white background, using the "Is Camera Ray" output of a Light Path node as the mix factor:

[image: BW2]

If you want to remove all reflections from the HDRI and replace it with pure white, mix the Environment Background with a plain white Background, using either "Is Reflection Ray" or "Is Glossy Ray" (depending on your needs) from the Light Path Node as a mix factor:

[image: BW3]

Comment: Thanks, it worked, kind of. The background color doesn't influence the objects anymore, but for some reason, the background turned into a single color, instead of showing the scene. For example, I have an image of green grass and yellow flowers. What I use it as a background, I only get a chartreuse color background. Do you know what when wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure. Just to confirm. you used an Environment Texture for your background and not an Image Texture, correct?

Comment: I used an environment texture like this: [blender screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4qeV.jpg) [background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvNKf.png)

Comment: See how in your screenshot, the image texture node says "linear", and then "flat" below it. Now see in my screenshot it says "linear" and  "equirectangular" instead? That's because the node I am using is an _Environment Texture_ node, and yours is an _Image Texture_ node. When you add the node for the image, pick _Environment Texture_ from the list and use that.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Turns out I *was* using an image texture.